# Promise `finally` is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am using Typescript and I have added `import 'promise.prototype.finally'` to the top of my `index.js` (in fact I've added it in multiple places).

When I use a promise I am getting `client.get(...).then(...).finally is not a function`.

I don't understand why this is not working, and I don't know what other information I can provide to help with debugging or where I would go to find out why this it not working!

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just importing [the package `promise.prototype.finally`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/promise.prototype.finally) doesn't do anything; the import doesn't have any side effects. You need to import it with a name, like this:

```
import promiseFinally from 'promise.prototype.finally';
```

Then call its `shim()` function to patch the global `Promise` prototype:

```
promiseFinally.shim();
```

You will then be able to use it as a method, like in your example.

You can put this at the top of your main entry point file if you have one. If not, you can at least put it at the top of the files where you know you're going to need it.

Comment: Is this still required even when typescript target is set to es2018?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as `import * as promiseFinally from 'promise.prototype.finally';`